# svn diff software that simply downloads changesets

Tags: svn, diff

Does anyone know any simple software (preferably without installation) that allows to download changesets of specified revisions and save them as "changesetX.diff/.patch"? For some reason Windows console allows very limited amount of lines, I can only get up to 298 lines in there, that's only a few files at best.
I'm talking about "svn diff repo@this repo@that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can change the size of the console buffer. Right click > Properties > Layout > Screen Buffer Size
2. You can redirect the output of svn diff to a file, no need to copy paste. `svn diff foo bar > foo-to-bar.diff`

Comment: The buffer size is 50, and number is 4, but the numbers kind of don't match... Guess I'll try to output to file, thanks :)

Comment: Took me an hour but in the end I made a handy batch file with proper input to do this :) I suppose the question can be closed then.